# How do I place AdMob banner on the bottom?

Tags: ios, admob, iad

How can I place the banner form AdMob on the bottom of the screen? I'm using AdMob as a Relay for when the iAd banner fails to load, but the AdMob banner appears at the top of the screen. I've looked up many ways to do it but non of them work.

here is my code:
.h

```
@interface Class_ScoreViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate,ADBannerViewDelegate>
{
    GADBannerView *bannerViewAdMob_;
    ADBannerView *adView;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet ADBannerView *adView;
```

.m

```
@synthesize adView;
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
    NSLog(@"-----------Displaying Ad-------------");
    [adView setHidden:NO];
    bannerViewAdMob_.hidden = YES;
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"------------Ad Error-------------");
    [adView setHidden:YES];
    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;


    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        if (screenSize.height > 480.0f) {
            //iPhone 5
            bannerViewAdMob_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height- 89 -GAD_SIZE_320x50.height, GAD_SIZE_320x50.width, GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];

        }
        else{
            //iPhone 4
            bannerViewAdMob_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height-GAD_SIZE_320x50.height, GAD_SIZE_320x50.width, GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];


        }
    // Create a view of the standard size at the top of the screen.
    // Available AdSize constants are explained in GADAdSize.h.
    bannerViewAdMob_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];

    // Specify the ad's "unit identifier". This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
    bannerViewAdMob_.adUnitID = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    // Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
    // the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
    bannerViewAdMob_.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerViewAdMob_];

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
    [bannerViewAdMob_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    adView.delegate = self;
    [adView setHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're overriding your variable, check the

```
 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        if (screenSize.height > 480.0f)
            bannerViewAdMob_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height- 89 -GAD_SIZE_320x50.height, GAD_SIZE_320x50.width, GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];
        else
            bannerViewAdMob_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height-GAD_SIZE_320x50.height, GAD_SIZE_320x50.width, GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];

    bannerViewAdMob_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner]; // here is you overwrite
```

to place it properly - set frame/bounds properties after you call initWithAdSize

Comment: would you also happen to know why the adMob ad doesnt hide after the iAd reloads again?

Comment: are you sure it reloads? place breakpoint at `bannerViewAdMob_.hidden = YES;` to see if it really happens

Comment: I can see the iAd behind the adMob Ad

Comment: Yes the break point does get there but it doesnt hide the banner from admob

Comment: I think it is because you added several subview in `[self.view addSubview:bannerViewAdMob_];` and try to hide only last one

Comment: so... how do i fix it? haha

Comment: at the beginning of `didFailToReceiveAdWithError` check whether `bannerViewAdMob_` is null or not, if null - do as you did, create, if not null - just show it